# Align column elements bottom - WordPress CSS

Tags: html, css, wordpress, flexbox

I am using Wordpress with a theme called Flatsome. I know how to use CSS but because of the HTML and CSS Wordpress and the theme creates I have no clue how to fix this.

I have one row with three equal sized columns. But the text for some products is much longer than for other products as you can see in my example. I have already tried to apply `display: flex` and `flex: 1 1 auto` to the `div`s but this will just led to the problem to either `align-self: start` or `align-self: end` the whole column.

But my goal is to have **just the button** aligned at the same `y` line in each column. So they should always be aligned vertically at the same `y` coordinate independently from the size and length of the text above.

How is this possible? Here my HTML and CSS (I just copied the WordPress CSS, don't wonder why it is so long)

Please expand the snippet otherwise the columns will be displayed in a mobile layout!

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.digital-media-products.de/mycss.css"/>

<div class="related related-products-wrapper product-section" style="background-color: white">

                    <h3 class="product-section-title container-width product-section-title-related pt-half pb-half uppercase">
                Products        </h3>
        

    
  
    <div class="row equalize-box large-columns-5 medium-columns-3 small-columns-2 row-small">
  
        
                    
<div class="product-small col has-hover product type-product post-10755 status-publish instock product_cat-schwarztee has-post-thumbnail taxable shipping-taxable purchasable product-type-simple">
    <div class="col-inner">
    
<div class="badge-container absolute left top z-1">
</div>
    <div class="product-small box ">
        <div class="box-image">
            <div class="image-zoom-fade">
                <a href="https://dertee.de/shop/fluffy-berry/">
                    <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/1000" class="attachment-woocommerce_thumbnail size-woocommerce_thumbnail" alt="" sizes="(max-width: 1000px) 100vw, 1000px" width="1000" height="1000">             </a>
            </div>
            <div class="image-tools is-small top right show-on-hover">
                            </div>
            <div class="image-tools is-small hide-for-small bottom left show-on-hover">
                            </div>
            <div class="image-tools grid-tools text-center hide-for-small bottom hover-slide-in show-on-hover">
                            </div>
                    </div><!-- box-image -->

        <div class="box-text box-text-products text-center grid-style-2">
            <div class="title-wrapper">     <p class="category uppercase is-smaller no-text-overflow product-cat op-7">
            Schwarztee      </p>
    <p class="name product-title" style="height: 23px;"><a href="https://dertee.de/shop/fluffy-berry/">Fluffy Berry</a></p><i id="product-subtitle-10755" class="product-subtitle subtitle-10755">Heidelbeere + Cranberry + Sahne</i></div><div class="price-wrapper" style="height: 34px;"><p class="price"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">10,95&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">€</span></span></p>
        <div class="wgm-info woocommerce-de_price_taxrate "></div>
        <div class="wgm-info woocommerce_de_versandkosten">zzgl. <a class="versandkosten" href="https://dertee.de/versand-und-zahlung/" target="_blank">Versand</a></div>
        </div><div class="add-to-cart-button" style="height: 98px;"><a href="?add-to-cart=10755" data-quantity="1" class="primary is-small mb-0 button product_type_simple add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart is-outline" data-product_id="10755" data-product_sku="" aria-label="„Fluffy Berry“ zu deinem Warenkorb hinzufügen" rel="nofollow">In den Warenkorb</a></div>     </div><!-- box-text -->
    </div><!-- box -->
        </div><!-- .col-inner -->
</div><!-- col -->

        
                    
<div class="product-small col has-hover product type-product post-10758 status-publish instock product_cat-schwarztee has-post-thumbnail taxable shipping-taxable purchasable product-type-simple">
    <div class="col-inner">
    
<div class="badge-container absolute left top z-1">
</div>
    <div class="product-small box ">
        <div class="box-image">
            <div class="image-zoom-fade">
                <a href="https://dertee.de/shop/el-guapo/">
                    <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/1000" class="attachment-woocommerce_thumbnail size-woocommerce_thumbnail" alt="" sizes="(max-width: 1000px) 100vw, 1000px" width="1000" height="1000">             </a>
            </div>
            <div class="image-tools is-small top right show-on-hover">
                            </div>
            <div class="image-tools is-small hide-for-small bottom left show-on-hover">
                            </div>
            <div class="image-tools grid-tools text-center hide-for-small bottom hover-slide-in show-on-hover">
                            </div>
                    </div><!-- box-image -->

        <div class="box-text box-text-products text-center grid-style-2">
            <div class="title-wrapper">     <p class="category uppercase is-smaller no-text-overflow product-cat op-7">
            Schwarztee      </p>
    <p class="name product-title" style="height: 23px;"><a href="https://dertee.de/shop/el-guapo/">El Guapo</a></p><i id="product-subtitle-10758" class="product-subtitle subtitle-10758">Mango Vollreif</i></div><div class="price-wrapper" style="height: 34px;"><p class="price"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">8,95&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">€</span></span></p>
        <div class="wgm-info woocommerce-de_price_taxrate "></div>
        <div class="wgm-info woocommerce_de_versandkosten">zzgl. <a class="versandkosten" href="https://dertee.de/versand-und-zahlung/" target="_blank">Versand</a></div>
        </div><div class="add-to-cart-button" style="height: 98px;"><a href="?add-to-cart=10758" data-quantity="1" class="primary is-small mb-0 button product_type_simple add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart is-outline" data-product_id="10758" data-product_sku="" aria-label="„El Guapo“ zu deinem Warenkorb hinzufügen" rel="nofollow">In den Warenkorb</a></div>     </div><!-- box-text -->
    </div><!-- box -->
        </div><!-- .col-inner -->
</div><!-- col -->

        
                    
<div class="product-small col has-hover product type-product post-10757 status-publish last instock product_cat-schwarztee has-post-thumbnail taxable shipping-taxable purchasable product-type-simple">
    <div class="col-inner">
    
<div class="badge-container absolute left top z-1">
</div>
    <div class="product-small box ">
        <div class="box-image">
            <div class="image-zoom-fade">
                <a href="https://dertee.de/shop/royal-rumble/">
                    <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/1000" class="attachment-woocommerce_thumbnail size-woocommerce_thumbnail" alt="" sizes="(max-width: 1000px) 100vw, 1000px" width="1000" height="1000">             </a>
            </div>
            <div class="image-tools is-small top right show-on-hover">
                            </div>
            <div class="image-tools is-small hide-for-small bottom left show-on-hover">
                            </div>
            <div class="image-tools grid-tools text-center hide-for-small bottom hover-slide-in show-on-hover">
                            </div>
                    </div><!-- box-image -->

        <div class="box-text box-text-products text-center grid-style-2">
            <div class="title-wrapper">     <p class="category uppercase is-smaller no-text-overflow product-cat op-7">
            Schwarztee      </p>
    <p class="name product-title" style="height: 23px;"><a href="https://dertee.de/shop/royal-rumble/">Royal Rumble</a></p><i id="product-subtitle-10757" class="product-subtitle subtitle-10757">Granatapfel + Goji + Sanddornbeere + Himbeere + Guarana</i></div><div class="price-wrapper" style="height: 34px;"><p class="price"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">12,95&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">€</span></span></p>
        <div class="wgm-info woocommerce-de_price_taxrate "></div>
        <div class="wgm-info woocommerce_de_versandkosten">zzgl. <a class="versandkosten" href="https://dertee.de/versand-und-zahlung/" target="_blank">Versand</a></div>
        </div><div class="add-to-cart-button" style="height: 98px;"><a href="?add-to-cart=10757" data-quantity="1" class="primary is-small mb-0 button product_type_simple add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart is-outline" data-product_id="10757" data-product_sku="" aria-label="„Royal Rumble“ zu deinem Warenkorb hinzufügen" rel="nofollow">In den Warenkorb</a></div>     </div><!-- box-text -->
    </div><!-- box -->
        </div><!-- .col-inner -->
</div><!-- col -->

        
        </div>
    </div>
```

Kind regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you can't really change the HTML structure since you are using a template. For this, you can still use flex-box but you need to specify the height for the information boxes (`.box-text`), then simply use `margin-top: auto` on the button

```css
.box-text {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 300px;
}

.add-to-cart-button {
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.digital-media-products.de/mycss.css" />

<div class="related related-products-wrapper product-section" style="background-color: white">

  <h3 class="product-section-title container-width product-section-title-related pt-half pb-half uppercase">
    Products </h3>

  <div class="row equalize-box large-columns-5 medium-columns-3 small-columns-2 row-small">

    <div class="product-small col has-hover product type-product post-10755 status-publish instock product_cat-schwarztee has-post-thumbnail taxable shipping-taxable purchasable product-type-simple">
      <div class="col-inner">

        <div class="badge-container absolute left top z-1">
        </div>
        <div class="product-small box ">
          <div class="box-image">
            <div class="image-zoom-fade">
              <a href="https://dertee.de/shop/fluffy-berry/">
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/1000" class="attachment-woocommerce_thumbnail size-woocommerce_thumbnail" alt="" sizes="(max-width: 1000px) 100vw, 1000px" width="1000" height="1000"> </a>
            </div>
            <div class="image-tools is-small top right show-on-hover">
            </div>
            <div class="image-tools is-small hide-for-small bottom left show-on-hover">
            </div>
            <div class="image-tools grid-tools text-center hide-for-small bottom hover-slide-in show-on-hover">
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- box-image -->

          <div class="box-text box-text-products text-center grid-style-2">
            <div class="title-wrapper">
              <p class="category uppercase is-smaller no-text-overflow product-cat op-7">
                Schwarztee </p>
              <p class="name product-title" style="height: 23px;"><a href="https://dertee.de/shop/fluffy-berry/">Fluffy Berry</a></p><i id="product-subtitle-10755" class="product-subtitle subtitle-10755">Heidelbeere + Cranberry + Sahne</i></div>
            <div class="price-wrapper" style="height: 34px;">
              <p class="price"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">10,95&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">€</span></span>
              </p>
              <div class="wgm-info woocommerce-de_price_taxrate "></div>
              <div class="wgm-info woocommerce_de_versandkosten">zzgl. <a class="versandkosten" href="https://dertee.de/versand-und-zahlung/" target="_blank">Versand</a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="add-to-cart-button" style="height: 98px;"><a href="?add-to-cart=10755" data-quantity="1" class="primary is-small mb-0 button product_type_simple add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart is-outline" data-product_id="10755" data-product_sku="" aria-label="„Fluffy Berry“ zu deinem Warenkorb hinzufügen"
                rel="nofollow">In den Warenkorb</a></div>
          </div>
          <!-- box-text -->
        </div>
        <!-- box -->
      </div>
      <!-- .col-inner -->
    </div>
    <!-- col -->

    <div class="product-small col has-hover product type-product post-10758 status-publish instock product_cat-schwarztee has-post-thumbnail taxable shipping-taxable purchasable product-type-simple">
      <div class="col-inner">

        <div class="badge-container absolute left top z-1">
        </div>
        <div class="product-small box ">
          <div class="box-image">
            <div class="image-zoom-fade">
              <a href="https://dertee.de/shop/el-guapo/">
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/1000" class="attachment-woocommerce_thumbnail size-woocommerce_thumbnail" alt="" sizes="(max-width: 1000px) 100vw, 1000px" width="1000" height="1000"> </a>
            </div>
            <div class="image-tools is-small top right show-on-hover">
            </div>
            <div class="image-tools is-small hide-for-small bottom left show-on-hover">
            </div>
            <div class="image-tools grid-tools text-center hide-for-small bottom hover-slide-in show-on-hover">
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- box-image -->

          <div class="box-text box-text-products text-center grid-style-2">
            <div class="title-wrapper">
              <p class="category uppercase is-smaller no-text-overflow product-cat op-7">
                Schwarztee </p>
              <p class="name product-title" style="height: 23px;"><a href="https://dertee.de/shop/el-guapo/">El Guapo</a></p><i id="product-subtitle-10758" class="product-subtitle subtitle-10758">Mango Vollreif</i></div>
            <div class="price-wrapper" style="height: 34px;">
              <p class="price"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">8,95&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">€</span></span>
              </p>
              <div class="wgm-info woocommerce-de_price_taxrate "></div>
              <div class="wgm-info woocommerce_de_versandkosten">zzgl. <a class="versandkosten" href="https://dertee.de/versand-und-zahlung/" target="_blank">Versand</a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="add-to-cart-button" style="height: 98px;"><a href="?add-to-cart=10758" data-quantity="1" class="primary is-small mb-0 button product_type_simple add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart is-outline" data-product_id="10758" data-product_sku="" aria-label="„El Guapo“ zu deinem Warenkorb hinzufügen"
                rel="nofollow">In den Warenkorb</a></div>
          </div>
          <!-- box-text -->
        </div>
        <!-- box -->
      </div>
      <!-- .col-inner -->
    </div>
    <!-- col -->

    <div class="product-small col has-hover product type-product post-10757 status-publish last instock product_cat-schwarztee has-post-thumbnail taxable shipping-taxable purchasable product-type-simple">
      <div class="col-inner">

        <div class="badge-container absolute left top z-1">
        </div>
        <div class="product-small box ">
          <div class="box-image">
            <div class="image-zoom-fade">
              <a href="https://dertee.de/shop/royal-rumble/">
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/1000" class="attachment-woocommerce_thumbnail size-woocommerce_thumbnail" alt="" sizes="(max-width: 1000px) 100vw, 1000px" width="1000" height="1000"> </a>
            </div>
            <div class="image-tools is-small top right show-on-hover">
            </div>
            <div class="image-tools is-small hide-for-small bottom left show-on-hover">
            </div>
            <div class="image-tools grid-tools text-center hide-for-small bottom hover-slide-in show-on-hover">
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- box-image -->

          <div class="box-text box-text-products text-center grid-style-2">
            <div class="title-wrapper">
              <p class="category uppercase is-smaller no-text-overflow product-cat op-7">
                Schwarztee </p>
              <p class="name product-title" style="height: 23px;"><a href="https://dertee.de/shop/royal-rumble/">Royal Rumble</a></p><i id="product-subtitle-10757" class="product-subtitle subtitle-10757">Granatapfel + Goji + Sanddornbeere + Himbeere + Guarana</i></div>
            <div class="price-wrapper" style="height: 34px;">
              <p class="price"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">12,95&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">€</span></span>
              </p>
              <div class="wgm-info woocommerce-de_price_taxrate "></div>
              <div class="wgm-info woocommerce_de_versandkosten">zzgl. <a class="versandkosten" href="https://dertee.de/versand-und-zahlung/" target="_blank">Versand</a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="add-to-cart-button" style="height: 98px;"><a href="?add-to-cart=10757" data-quantity="1" class="primary is-small mb-0 button product_type_simple add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart is-outline" data-product_id="10757" data-product_sku="" aria-label="„Royal Rumble“ zu deinem Warenkorb hinzufügen"
                rel="nofollow">In den Warenkorb</a></div>
          </div>
          <!-- box-text -->
        </div>
        <!-- box -->
      </div>
      <!-- .col-inner -->
    </div>
    <!-- col -->

  </div>
</div>
```

For `non-static` height solutions, it's going to require more work on the child elements of `.product-small`. **The goal** is essentially to get the height of the info box (`.box-text`) to be similar for each element relative to the `.product-small`, i.e., the "main" container (of course for this to work, the main container should already be the same height as its sibling main containers). In order to do this, simply utilize responsive measurements such as `%`. Example:

```css
.col-inner {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}

.product-small.box {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}

.box-text {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
}

.add-to-cart-button {
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.digital-media-products.de/mycss.css" />

<div class="related related-products-wrapper product-section" style="background-color: white">

  <h3 class="product-section-title container-width product-section-title-related pt-half pb-half uppercase">
    Products </h3>

  <div class="row equalize-box large-columns-5 medium-columns-3 small-columns-2 row-small">

    <div class="product-small col has-hover product type-product post-10755 status-publish instock product_cat-schwarztee has-post-thumbnail taxable shipping-taxable purchasable product-type-simple">
      <div class="col-inner">

        <div class="badge-container absolute left top z-1">
        </div>
        <div class="product-small box ">
          <div class="box-image">
            <div class="image-zoom-fade">
              <a href="https://dertee.de/shop/fluffy-berry/">
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/1000" class="attachment-woocommerce_thumbnail size-woocommerce_thumbnail" alt="" sizes="(max-width: 1000px) 100vw, 1000px" width="1000" height="1000"> </a>
            </div>
            <div class="image-tools is-small top right show-on-hover">
            </div>
            <div class="image-tools is-small hide-for-small bottom left show-on-hover">
            </div>
            <div class="image-tools grid-tools text-center hide-for-small bottom hover-slide-in show-on-hover">
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- box-image -->

          <div class="box-text box-text-products text-center grid-style-2">
            <div class="title-wrapper">
              <p class="category uppercase is-smaller no-text-overflow product-cat op-7">
                Schwarztee </p>
              <p class="name product-title" style="height: 23px;"><a href="https://dertee.de/shop/fluffy-berry/">Fluffy Berry</a></p><i id="product-subtitle-10755" class="product-subtitle subtitle-10755">Heidelbeere + Cranberry + Sahne</i></div>
            <div class="price-wrapper" style="height: 34px;">
              <p class="price"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">10,95&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">€</span></span>
              </p>
              <div class="wgm-info woocommerce-de_price_taxrate "></div>
              <div class="wgm-info woocommerce_de_versandkosten">zzgl. <a class="versandkosten" href="https://dertee.de/versand-und-zahlung/" target="_blank">Versand</a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="add-to-cart-button" style="height: 98px;"><a href="?add-to-cart=10755" data-quantity="1" class="primary is-small mb-0 button product_type_simple add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart is-outline" data-product_id="10755" data-product_sku="" aria-label="„Fluffy Berry“ zu deinem Warenkorb hinzufügen"
                rel="nofollow">In den Warenkorb</a></div>
          </div>
          <!-- box-text -->
        </div>
        <!-- box -->
      </div>
      <!-- .col-inner -->
    </div>
    <!-- col -->

    <div class="product-small col has-hover product type-product post-10758 status-publish instock product_cat-schwarztee has-post-thumbnail taxable shipping-taxable purchasable product-type-simple">
      <div class="col-inner">

        <div class="badge-container absolute left top z-1">
        </div>
        <div class="product-small box ">
          <div class="box-image">
            <div class="image-zoom-fade">
              <a href="https://dertee.de/shop/el-guapo/">
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/1000" class="attachment-woocommerce_thumbnail size-woocommerce_thumbnail" alt="" sizes="(max-width: 1000px) 100vw, 1000px" width="1000" height="1000"> </a>
            </div>
            <div class="image-tools is-small top right show-on-hover">
            </div>
            <div class="image-tools is-small hide-for-small bottom left show-on-hover">
            </div>
            <div class="image-tools grid-tools text-center hide-for-small bottom hover-slide-in show-on-hover">
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- box-image -->

          <div class="box-text box-text-products text-center grid-style-2">
            <div class="title-wrapper">
              <p class="category uppercase is-smaller no-text-overflow product-cat op-7">
                Schwarztee </p>
              <p class="name product-title" style="height: 23px;"><a href="https://dertee.de/shop/el-guapo/">El Guapo</a></p><i id="product-subtitle-10758" class="product-subtitle subtitle-10758">Mango Vollreif</i></div>
            <div class="price-wrapper" style="height: 34px;">
              <p class="price"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">8,95&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">€</span></span>
              </p>
              <div class="wgm-info woocommerce-de_price_taxrate "></div>
              <div class="wgm-info woocommerce_de_versandkosten">zzgl. <a class="versandkosten" href="https://dertee.de/versand-und-zahlung/" target="_blank">Versand</a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="add-to-cart-button" style="height: 98px;"><a href="?add-to-cart=10758" data-quantity="1" class="primary is-small mb-0 button product_type_simple add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart is-outline" data-product_id="10758" data-product_sku="" aria-label="„El Guapo“ zu deinem Warenkorb hinzufügen"
                rel="nofollow">In den Warenkorb</a></div>
          </div>
          <!-- box-text -->
        </div>
        <!-- box -->
      </div>
      <!-- .col-inner -->
    </div>
    <!-- col -->

    <div class="product-small col has-hover product type-product post-10757 status-publish last instock product_cat-schwarztee has-post-thumbnail taxable shipping-taxable purchasable product-type-simple">
      <div class="col-inner">

        <div class="badge-container absolute left top z-1">
        </div>
        <div class="product-small box ">
          <div class="box-image">
            <div class="image-zoom-fade">
              <a href="https://dertee.de/shop/royal-rumble/">
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/1000" class="attachment-woocommerce_thumbnail size-woocommerce_thumbnail" alt="" sizes="(max-width: 1000px) 100vw, 1000px" width="1000" height="1000"> </a>
            </div>
            <div class="image-tools is-small top right show-on-hover">
            </div>
            <div class="image-tools is-small hide-for-small bottom left show-on-hover">
            </div>
            <div class="image-tools grid-tools text-center hide-for-small bottom hover-slide-in show-on-hover">
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- box-image -->

          <div class="box-text box-text-products text-center grid-style-2">
            <div class="title-wrapper">
              <p class="category uppercase is-smaller no-text-overflow product-cat op-7">
                Schwarztee </p>
              <p class="name product-title" style="height: 23px;"><a href="https://dertee.de/shop/royal-rumble/">Royal Rumble</a></p><i id="product-subtitle-10757" class="product-subtitle subtitle-10757">Granatapfel + Goji + Sanddornbeere + Himbeere + Guarana</i></div>
            <div class="price-wrapper" style="height: 34px;">
              <p class="price"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">12,95&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">€</span></span>
              </p>
              <div class="wgm-info woocommerce-de_price_taxrate "></div>
              <div class="wgm-info woocommerce_de_versandkosten">zzgl. <a class="versandkosten" href="https://dertee.de/versand-und-zahlung/" target="_blank">Versand</a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="add-to-cart-button" style="height: 98px;"><a href="?add-to-cart=10757" data-quantity="1" class="primary is-small mb-0 button product_type_simple add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart is-outline" data-product_id="10757" data-product_sku="" aria-label="„Royal Rumble“ zu deinem Warenkorb hinzufügen"
                rel="nofollow">In den Warenkorb</a></div>
          </div>
          <!-- box-text -->
        </div>
        <!-- box -->
      </div>
      <!-- .col-inner -->
    </div>
    <!-- col -->

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thats what I have been searching for. Thanks! Just one more question: Is it possible to have the `height` variable instead of setting it to `300px`? Otherwise it isn't really going to be a solution for responsive design.

Comment: You can easily do the same implementation minus the static `height` CSS property. But, it would require HTML structure changes. If you go ahead and open the inspect element tool, you will notice that all your `.product-small` elements have the same height. Simply attach the button there as the child and position at the bottom using the properties I mentioned on my answer.

Comment: Thank you mate! Very appreciate your effort! It's working. But I am wondering why the button is getting pushed down when setting `margin-top: auto;`. How does the botton knows it belongs to the end of the flexbox? Normally you say `align-self: end`. How does that work?

Comment: It will behave somewhat similarly to how `auto` margins work for `margin-left` & `margin-right` on a `block` element. Setting `margin-top: auto` on the button took up the extra space in the flex container. Specs: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#auto-margins